# What are some popular stereotypes of mathematical research?

Tags: soft-question, research

I know this is a soft question, but what are some of the popular stereotypes of mathematical research? I guess that one would be that mathematicians just do hard arithmetic or algebraic calculations all day, but that might not actually be a stereotype. So, I am just curious, what are the stereotypes of mathematical research in the eyes of the general public?

Comment: The **really** general public is not aware that there is such a thing as mathematical research, so they can't have a stereotype about it.

Comment: In France there is an old (1893) precursor of comics, that portrays a mathematician, nicknamed Cosinus. He accumulates stereotypes, the most proeminent being absent-mindedness. But he is also a physicist - as were many people at that time, e.g. Henri Poincaré. The expression "savant Cosinus" is still used to designate an absent-minded, unrealistic, socially impaired, unable to do simple everyday tasks, scientific man. https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Id%C3%A9e_fixe_du_savant_Cosinus

Comment: I am always fascinated when in a movie featuring a genius mathematician, they are distracted by numbers and formulas which they see flying around. I know many mathematicians who are occasionally distracted by something they "see" in their heads, I just think it is never numbers or formulas.